# C++ callback to non-static interface method

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a class A that should call a non-static class method from an interface class B, with signature expressed by, say, the following function pointer:

`bool (B::*check)(int) const`

Such method would be implemented by a set of classes {C} implementing B, each with multiple methods matching the above signature. I therefore need to bind the callback from A towards B, which in turn would delegate to the chosen method from C.

**Edited with some code:**

This is a sketch of what I have in mind. Beware that this is only an example of the requirement above, nothing in the organization of the code is mandatory outside, perhaps, class A.

```
class B {
  public:
    bool check(int val) const {
       // call to a binded method with a given signature (sig) on a Cx class
       ...
    }
};

class C1: public B {
  ...
  // a method implementing the (sig) signature
  // another method implementing the (sig) signature
};


class C2: public B {
  ...
  // a method implementing the (sig) signature
  // another method implementing the (sig) signature
};

class A {
  public:
  ...
  private:
    bool result;
    int val;

    void call_check(B const& b) const {
      result = b.check(val);      
    }
  ...
};
```

It that possible in C++? Or equivalently, what would be a solution that allows A to know of class B only?

To my puzzlement, I haven't found a solution around for this very specific need.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your question where your problem lies.  If C implements B, why can't A just take a reference to B and call the method on it?  Why do you need function pointers at all?

Comment: Indeed, I am still bouncing between the approach of passing a function pointer directly to A and that of working out the delegation inside the B class. The important thing is to have A interface to one class only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Massive Edit**

I think I got what you want, based on some heavy type-casting.

Note that I do **NOT** recommend this technique.  Although my example works, I believe there are some big pitfalls here that could really screw things up.

As before, Class `A` can accept both a method of the proper signature and an object (of type `B`, or derived from type `B`, such as your `C` classes), and call the specified method on the specified object.

Class `B` does not actually have any methods at all, and only acts as a common base-class for the two classes `C1` & `C2`.

At the bottom is a `main` that demonstrates how this is used.   I left out the implementation of the two `SetCallback***` methods, as they're trivial.

```
class B
{   public: // Has nothing, only serves as base-class for C1 and C2.        
};

class C1: public B
{
    public: bool DoThis(int x) const { return true; }
};

class C2: public B
{
    public: bool DoThat(int x) const { return false; }
};

class A
{
    private:
        bool (B::*m_check)(int) const;
        B* m_Obj;

    public:
        void SetCallbackFunction(bool (B::*fnc)(int) const)
        {   m_check = fnc; }

        void SetCallbackObject(B* pB)
        {   m_Obj = pB;  }

        bool InvokeCallback(int val)
        {
            return (m_Obj->*m_check)(val);
        }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    C1 c;

    bool (C1::*func)(int) const;
    bool (B::*b_func)(int) const;

    func = &C1::DoThis;
    b_func = (bool (B::*)(int) const)(func);   // Dangerous Typecasting.  Use caution!

    a.SetCallbackFunction(b_func);
    a.SetCallbackObject((B*)(&c));   // A simpler, safer typecast.

    a.InvokeCallback(5);  // Ends up calling C1::DoThis.

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a fine and very clean solution, but there is a final step missing: what if I have C derived from B where another function matching B::m_check signature is present? The SetCallbackFunction won't let me bind to C:: functions. Could you integrate your code to clarify how I should do this? (and maybe add the SetCallbackFunction and SetCallbackObject, even if are trivial, for other readers' sake) Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: I'm sorry, now I got it: I missed making B's methods virtual. Could you integrate the changes above to have the example fully answer my question?

Comment: There is still an open point here: the C classes will have their own distinct methods, sharing only the signature. Since they do not have to implement the methods that they do not care about, the B interface has to provide empty implementations for all its virtual methods. This smells a bit. Could something be done around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do is not to use a member function pointer, but rather a higher order construct like `function` (either `boost` or C++11) and register the callbacks with `bind` (again, `boost` or C++11).

Answer (score 1):

Pointers-to-member-functions are available, and do exactly what you want.  However, just be aware that they are not actually "pointers", but are "pointer-like", since it is *possible* that proper lookup/calling must go through the "vptr" table(s) associated with a class that may possibly have more-than-one-parent.

In short:  Yes, you can have it.  If you implement in a template, you do *not* need to include the target headers (but you *would* need to implement the target class headers at the point of code expansion).  If you implement as a non-template, then you *could* forward-declare the member functions and get it to work.  Or, you could simply include the target class-type headers.

Since multiple target functions are available, yes, at the point of actual binding, you must include the header (you don't need the header if this is a template implementation):

```
class MyA {
public:
  bool foo1(int) const;
  bool foo2(int) const;
};

void MyFunc(void) {
  bool (MyA::*my_ptr_to_func)(int) const;
  my_ptr_to_func = &MyA::foo2;

  MyA my_a;

  // call it
  if((my_a.*my_ptr_to_func)(42))
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**, based on your updated code, it seems like you merely want to make "`bool B::check(int) const`" to be "`virtual`" in the base class, and override/re-implement that function in the derived "`C1`" and "`C2`" classes?

Yes, the `virtual` function will be called (the implementation in the `C1` and `C2` classes), even though your pointer was originally to the `B::check(int)` function.  This works, and is exactly *why* a pointer-to-member-function is not *exactly* a pointer, but is *pointer-like* (to permit your call to correctly execute the `virtual` code in the derived classes).

So, no fear: It will work, just put "`virtual`" on `B::check(int)` in the base.

Comment: My code can be misleading in that sense, on a first glance: each Cx can provide **more than one** method matching the signature. If it were one only, then using a virtual function would be the solution. B has indeed the additional purpose of patching the desired implementation (coming from any method from any Cx that matches a (sig) signature) to A.

Comment: If the point-of-call is to a *function name*, other signatures won't matter (the name resolves).  If the point-of-call is through a *function pointer*, other signatures won't matter (the pointer is initially created through referencing a function name).  Where do you decide *which* of the signatures you want?

Comment: The approach of abelenky indeed most closely matches what I was looking for: **A** should call a method for binding the desired object from any **C** and method from **B**, then the **C** -s implement some or all of those methods. Still not ideal that **B** must necessarily provide a definition for all methods, because the **C** -s won't implement them all together.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the observer pattern to allow A to hold a vector of function pointers of type `bool (B::*check)(int) const`.

Classes in {C} could thus register through the observer pattern to A.  I don't see why you need an interface, B, explicitly if you use this form of pattern.  The interface will be guaranteed by the vector of function pointers requiring the signature of your chosen function pointer.